# Leaving out the .git directory on pypi

Tags: python, github, pypi

Can anyone tell me how to prevent the contents of the .git directory to be uploaded to PyPi. My MANIFEST.in looks like so:

```
global-include *.py *.js *.rst *.html *.css *.lyx *.pdf *.png *.gif *.jpg *.txt *.jar *.bat *
global-exclude *.pyc *.git .gitignore

prune Transcrypt/development/*.git
prune Transcrypt/development/attic
prune Transcrypt/development/docs
prune Transcrypt/development/experiments
```

My uploads get too big with the .git stuff around...
I've spend quite some time reading about this on the Internet, but so far nothing seems to work.

[edit]

But this does (Thanks, bastelflp for pointing in right direction)

```
global-include *.py *.js *.rst *.html *.css *.lyx *.pdf *.png *.gif *.jpg *.txt *.jar *.bat *
global-exclude *.pyc .gitignore

prune .git
prune Transcrypt/development/attic
prune Transcrypt/development/docs
prune Transcrypt/development/experiments
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you exclude **files** with the extension `.git` but not the **folder** `/.git`.

Try removing the `*` before your `.git` exclusions.