# Exclude a directory given by name in any (sub)directory in sdist

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

I want to remove all folders with a given name, say `.git` from a python sdist.

The name of the folder doesn't matter, the question is meant to be general. I use `.git` here because that was my use case: A subfolder can have a `.git` folder but `prune` (which automatically removes folders named `.git` [among others]) had to be disabled (setup.cfg: `[sdist] prune=1`).

From https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/ there is `prune .git` which does remove a `.git` **toplevel** folder.

But how can I remove any folder with that name? `distutils` always anchors the match expression to either start or beginning of a filepath and `**` is not supported to match any character including slashes.

What I tried from [Leaving out the .git directory on pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393320/leaving-out-the-git-directory-on-pypi): `global-exclude .git` but that doesn't work either as it matches files not folders.

The only workaround I see is to use:

```
prune .git
prune */.git
prune */*/.git
prune */*/*/.git
```

Is this intentional? A bug? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point of the question, but usually there is no need to do anything. I belive _distutils_ or _setuptools_ would never add such directories by default. Maybe showing the tree-like directory structure of the project as well as the content of its `setup.py` file could help us help you.

Comment: Good point. Prune is disabled as it would remove a legitimate `CVS` folder we happen to have. But the question is meant to be general, so it doesn't matter if the folder in question is `.git` or `test` or `foobar`. I guess `test` would be another good example: Remove all test folders from all (sub)packages. I edited the question

Comment: **1.** I do not understand the statement "_prune is disabled_", would you mind clarifying this bit? If there is a `CVS` directory that you need, then maybe use `graft path/to/CVS`, there could also be a _glob_ in there to include multiple `CVS` directories (`graft somepackage/**/CVS`). **2.** Have you tried `recursive-exclude somepackage/**/.git *`?

Comment: I see you mention not being able to use the `**` glob since it's not available in _distutils_. What about moving to _setuptools_?

Comment: 1. You can set `prune=0` in the `sdist` section of `setup.cfg` to disable the automatic pruning of `.git, CVS, ...`. This pruning happens **after** all commands from the manifest.in have been run, so there is no way to add a folder afterwards. **2.** the double-star is not supported with distutils and the page mentions it is undocumented on setuptools. Not sure if one can rely on that

Comment: I have had somewhat success with something like `global-exclude foo/*`, under _setuptools_ though. Maybe it fits your requirements.

Comment: Shouldn't we take the issue the other way around and re-enable the pruning? Then we see from there what should be included or excluded? Or is the disabling of the pruning strictly necessary?

Comment: @sinoroc Pruning must be disabled as otherwise it would remove a folder named "CVS" that should be included and there is no way to change that as pruning happens after all user actions

Comment: Is there Python code or data files in that `CVS` directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211124/discussion-between-flamefire-and-sinoroc).

Answer (score 2):

From current discussion I conclude: It is not easily possible with distutils.

So in order to exclude a folder from any subdirectory via distutils MANIFEST.in on should list every possible folder level:

```
prune .git
prune */.git
prune */*/.git
prune */*/*/.git
```

When using setuptools it is much easier: Adding `prune **/.git` removes the folder from any subdirectory including the root directory

Note however that a warning will be printed if no such folder is found (for both solutions, so for distutils there will actually be many warnings)

So it is better to avoid that situation altogether by only adding folders that should be added and remove ones that are known. The situation that a folder might exist somewhere is rare.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of `MANIFEST.in` being additive, not subtractive. It has some defaults [listed here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) and anything else besides what you explicitly specify is ignored.

(Using `tests` as an example in your comment isn't ideal, since all files matching `test/test*.py` are included by default.)

Given the following example:

```
$ tree .
.
├── bar
│   └── __init__.py
├── foo
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── foo
└── setup.py

$ cat setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my-package",
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

Running `python setup.py sdist` would result in the following being included as they are all modules:

```
bar/
bar/__init__.py
my_package/
my_package/__init__.py
my_package/bar/
my_package/bar/__init__.py
setup.py
```

And the following being excluded because they are not modules:

```
foo/
my_package/foo/
```

Similarly, all `.git` directories,  or really any directory without an `__init__.py` in it, would be excluded by default.

Comment: Ok and what would I do if I had a folder "foobar" in `my_package` or `my_package/bar` which I want to exclude generically? Oh and we are using distutils (for some reason, gotta check if we can switch to setuptools)

Comment: Like I said: if it's not a module (i.e. it doesn't have an `__init__.py` file inside it), it will be excluded by default. If it is a module, it doesn't really make sense to exclude it as this could lead to a broken distribution.

Comment: Ah, good to know. But here it doesn't help: I need to recursively include a folder and all files except (e.g.) a folder named "foobar". Those are not really packages but rather datafiles. Hence there is a `recursive-include myfolder *` in the MANIFEST.in

Comment: You're going to need to explicitly list filenames or filename patterns in that match what you want to include in `myfolder`, for example `recursive-include myfolder *.dat *.csv`.